# Why does numpy.linalg.solve() have non-constant computation time for same sized arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I've been using `numpy.linalg.solve(A,B)` to solve a linear equation. In my case: `A` is about 10,000x10,000 and `B` is around 10,000x5. If I initialize `A` and `B` randomly using:

```
A = numpy.random.rand(10000,10000)
B = numpy.random.rand(10000,5)
```

Then the computation time is <3 seconds. However, in my program that needs to solve this equation, the computational time is consistently about 14 seconds. This code is iterated over in a loop, so a speedup of almost 5 times is a big deal. Should the solution for `linalg.solve()` not be roughly constant for constant sized arrays?

Both implementations are using `float64`. And there is defintely enough ram (128 GB). I tried updating blas libraries on the computer (Ubuntu 16.04 - numpy installed with conda) and it showed improvements on the solutions from the randomly generated data, but not for the data in my program.

If anyone is looking for more specifics about the code, this is from line 27 of the .py file found at [1]. This program is doing registration of point clouds.

Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated.

[1]https://github.com/siavashk/pycpd/blob/master/pycpd/deformable_registration.py

Edit: 
To try and make this more reproducible, I've generated some code to try and get me to the suspect np.linalg.solve() line:

```
import numpy as np
import time

def gaussian_kernel(Y, beta):
    diff = Y[None,:,:] - Y[:,None,:]
    diff = diff**2
    diff = np.sum(diff, axis=2)
    return np.exp(-diff / (2 * beta**2))

def initialize_sigma2(X, Y):
    diff = X[None,:,:] - Y[:,None,:]
    err  = diff**2
    return np.sum(err) / (X.shape[0] * Y.shape[0] * X.shape[1])

alpha = 0.1
beta = 3

X = np.random.rand(10000,5) * 100
Y = X + X*0.1

N, D = X.shape
M, _ = Y.shape

G = gaussian_kernel(Y, beta)
sigma2 = initialize_sigma2(X,Y)

TY = Y + np.random.rand(10000,5)

P = np.sum((X[None,:,:] - TY[:,None,:])**2, axis=2)
P /= np.sum(P,axis=0)

P1 = np.sum(P, axis=1)
Np = np.sum(P1)

A = np.dot(np.diag(P1), G) + alpha * sigma2 * np.eye(M)
B = np.dot(P, X) - np.dot(np.diag(P1), Y)

%time W = np.linalg.solve(A,B)
```

However, this code does not produce the time lag. Everything in this is the same as in the current script... except, the actual creation of the X and Y arrays. These should be two point clouds that are roughly close to one another in 3D space - this is why I have created one based on the other.

Comment: Where are `self.P1`, `self.P`, and `self.X` defined, and what are their `shape`? Looking at the surrounding code hardly helps without being able to reproduce the effect.

Comment: Please include all relevant code in question itself [mcve].

Comment: Is your longer-running matrix close to singular?

Comment: @darksky, thanks for the response. self.P1 (10,000x1), self.P (10,000x10,000), self.X (10000x5). 

I apologize if the included link made things harder to grasp. I only added it in the event that there is something strange in there that helps. Really my question is whether or why numpy.linalg.solve() might take drastically different computation times on the same sized arrays (A,B). I will try to explain a bit better what is going on in the post.

Comment: @Julien, thanks for that. I've tried to do this, but I cant reproduce two arrays that have the same problem. The only other solution would be uploading large files of 3d mesh data, which I dont think follows the guidelines you've mentioned.  I've made code that should in theory be close, but doesnt produce the same time lag. I've attached this code above.

Comment: @hpaulj - Thanks for that question, I feel like you could be onto something. The determinant of the matrix is inf when calculated using np.linalg.det() - it indicates there is an overflow error (using float64).

Comment: @hpaulj Running some experiments, it doesn't seem that having a matrix very close to singular makes any difference in the computation time for me (Anaconda NumPy 1.15.4 with MKL on Windows).

Comment: @jdehesa thanks for looking into that. I wonder if I don't have enough precision? I only say this because of the fact that running np.linalg.det() on the suspect matrix lead to overflow. I'll try using higher precision and see if that has any effect.

Comment: By downcasting to float32 the operation sped up >10 fold (14s to ~1s). This makes me think there was a memory issue, no? However, when monitoring my system resources there is never a memory issue - and doing the same operation on a 64 bit array of random values works perfectly fine (3seconds compute time).